# Correctly filtering out LFI

Tags: php

How can I correctly filter out local file inclusion in PHP?
I've been searching but can't find a simple function to do this. As I understand it removing slashes isn't enough.

Comment: You need to expand your question - filter it out of where? what are you trying to avoid?

Comment: PHP outputting another file ex: example.com/index.php?page=../../etc/passwd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't ever use `include()` (or its relatives, like `require()` or `readfile()`) on user input. Ever.

Comment: There's simply not a safe way to filter the user input?

Comment: Not adequately. If you need to include files based on user input, you should probably either 1) look up the actual filename based on some key that's passed in or 2) keep a whitelist of approved filenames. Otherwise it's far too easy to accidentally allow access to an unintended file.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to avoid this is not to write code that `include()`'s from user input - there is usually no need to do this. Instead of having your URL be `foo.php?page=bar` just use `bar.php` as the URL.

If you absolutely must, you can go about filtering in a few ways. A white-list is easy:

```
$ok = array('foo.php', 'bar.php', 'baz.php');
$include = in_array($_GET['page'], $ok) ? $_GET['page'] : 'default.php';
include($include);
```

This only allows a pre-set list of included files.

Alternatively, you could filter with a regexp (but this is more prone to mistakes):

```
if (preg_match('!^[a-z]+\.php$!', $_GET['page'])){
    include($_GET['page']);
}else{
    include('default.php');
}
```

Comment: Why the latter example is bad, see:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/how-can-i-use-this-path-bypass-exploit-local-file-inclusion